# When index 0 beyond bounds for empty array how can stop tableview from loading the cell data from that array?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

When index 0 beyond bounds for empty array how can stop tableview from loading the cell data from that array? and dispay an alert message.

Comment: Can u explain in detail with some code??

Comment: if index Zero tableview cell not loading. Without data how it could be load

Comment: i think you got exception by zero index

Comment: See my (whyever downvoted?!) and shaik riyaz answer. They are both correct.

Comment: Here is anwser: Hold on guys, here is a solution. if the array count is not equal to zero then write [myTableView reloadData]; else you can display your alert meassage.

Answer (score 3):

try this ....

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     if(array!= nil)
     {
         return [array count];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hold on guys, here is a solution.
if the array count is not equal to zero then write  [myTableView reloadData];
else you can display your alert meassage.I have got exact answer for my question,sorry guys if did waste your time.

Answer (score -1):

You have to return the size of the array in this delegate metthod:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_dataArray count];
}
```

Google for an UITableView tutorial if your not familiar with this practice. It's pretty much the basics of UITableView programming.

Comment: Why is somebody downvoting correct answers?! Who wants to help others if one gets blamed for that?

Comment: I can confirm that this is a correct answer. If ivar *_dataArray* is `nil` or if the number of elements equals zero, the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`returns 0 (zero).

Comment: Thanks for backing though ;-)